# WP File Manager got an error

Tags: wordpress, function

I think I messed up I don't have the Cpanel access to this site and I'm using the WP File Manager to edit the function.php and I made a mistake and save it now I can't open it and it's returning as a parse error. I can't open anything it keeps showing the error. Anyone know how to fix this without Cpanel? I don't really wanna let my client know that I messed up I think I'm not gonna ask for the CPanel is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

Own your mistake. Tell the client as soon as you can. In future, Always ask for FTP or cPanel access beforehand.

If you cause a parse error in wordpress and have no FTP or SSH access, there's nothing that can be done.